# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter even though the parameter is passed

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, iis

I'm sending a `POST` request to URL `http://localhost/WebService.asmx/userworkinsert` with the following parameters.

```
UserId=a2eb8a30-68d3-4bfc-9d53-4e655b816df9&WorkId&TimePeriod_To_Month=Jan&NoticePeriodid=2&IsCurrentlyWorking=1&Employ_Type=1&TimePeriod_To_Year=1950&TimePeriod_From_Year=2011&JobProfile=profile&CompanyName=daacompany&JobTitle=dadesignation&Employ_Status
```

But it is responding with a server error and the message is following :

```
{
    "Message": "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'UserId'.",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException"
}
```

Even though the parameter `UserId` is passed with the request. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Although it works when I send a request using the webservice's automatically generate forms. I used intercepted the `POST` request and these were the parameters sent :

```
UserId=a2eb8a30-68d3-4bfc-9d53-4e655b816df9&WorkId=&JobTitle=xda+designation&CompanyName=xdacompany&IsCurrentlyWorking=1&NoticePeriodid=2&TimePeriod_From_Year=2011&TimePeriod_From_Month=Jan&TimePeriod_To_Year=1950&TimePeriod_To_Month=Jan&JobProfile=xprofile&Employ_Type=1&Employ_Status=
```

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**
`userworkinsert` webservice declaration.

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string userworkinsert(string UserId, string WorkId, string JobTitle, string CompanyName, string IsCurrentlyWorking
                              , string NoticePeriodid, string TimePeriod_From_Year, string TimePeriod_From_Month, string TimePeriod_To_Year, string TimePeriod_To_Month
                              , string JobProfile, string Employ_Type, string Employ_Status)
    {
        Jobsekeer obj_jobSeeker = new Jobsekeer();

        SqlParameter[] p = new SqlParameter[18];
        if (WorkId != "")
        {
            p[0] = new SqlParameter("@op", 2);
            p[1] = new SqlParameter("@WorkMaster_Id", WorkId);

        }
        else
        {
            p[0] = new SqlParameter("@op", 1);
            p[1] = new SqlParameter("@WorkMaster_Id", DBNull.Value);
        }

        p[2] = new SqlParameter("@UserID", UserId);
        p[3] = new SqlParameter("@JobTitle", JobTitle);
        p[4] = new SqlParameter("@CompanyName", CompanyName);
        p[5] = new SqlParameter("@CityID", DBNull.Value);
        p[6] = new SqlParameter("@Salary", DBNull.Value);
        p[7] = new SqlParameter("@SalaryTakenType", "Per Year");
        p[8] = new SqlParameter("@IsCurrentlyWorking", IsCurrentlyWorking);
        p[9] = new SqlParameter("@NoticePeriod", NoticePeriodid);


        p[10] = new SqlParameter("@TimePeriod_From_Year", TimePeriod_From_Year);
        p[11] = new SqlParameter("@TimePeriod_From_Month", TimePeriod_From_Month);
        p[12] = new SqlParameter("@TimePeriod_To_Year", TimePeriod_To_Year);
        p[13] = new SqlParameter("@TimePeriod_To_Month", TimePeriod_To_Month);

        p[14] = new SqlParameter("@JobProfile", JobProfile);
        p[15] = new SqlParameter("@Employ_Type", Employ_Type);
        p[16] = new SqlParameter("@Employ_Status", Employ_Status);
        p[17] = new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", UserId);



        string responseresult = "";
        string ressponsetext = "";
        try
        {
            if (obj_jobSeeker.WorkMaster_Insert_Update(p))
            {
                responseresult = "true";
                ressponsetext = "Sucess";
            }
            else
            {
                responseresult = "false";
                ressponsetext = "unsucessful";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            responseresult = "false";
            ressponsetext = "unsucessful";
        }
        user.Getinsertupdateresponse obj = new user.Getinsertupdateresponse();
        obj.Getinsertupdateresponseist = new user.clsinsertupdateresponse();
        obj.Getinsertupdateresponseist.response = responseresult;
        obj.Getinsertupdateresponseist.responsemsg = ressponsetext;

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer SObj = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        String JsonStr = SObj.Serialize(obj); Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        Context.Response.Write(JsonStr); Context.Response.End();

        return "";

    }
```

Comment: Can you paste your code which calling this method?

Comment: Do you use WebAPI or what?

Comment: @Marcin I'm using HTTPRequester firefox addon to send requests if that is what you're asking.

Comment: I asking for back-end, service-side. Because when I read 'I'm sending POST..' my first thought was that you are using WebAPI (REST) for you webservice, do you?

Comment: @Marcin I'm sorry.. I haven't worked on the server side code, I'm just consuming the API. How can I find out that you're asking me?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you create appropriate POST body? I always use something like this:

```
{
"CardId": 26,
"Login": "15462",
"AccessToken": "79f5828b-1e46-47ed-af1f-5d2c3739742b",
"Password": "8TpB9OZqlNkdBBvVfZITEqiM09c=",
"IsPinPresent": true,
"Puk": "",
"GivenName": "My Name"
```

}

EDIT:
Try to put userId Guid into ""

```
UserId="a2eb8a30-68d3-4bfc-9d53-4e655b816df9"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the next parameter, **WorkId** is not being assigned a value, could that be hampering with the request?

Comment: I don't think so. No. Because that intercepted request I put at the and does not have that parameters assigned a value either and it just works fine.

Comment: How does the controller look like? How is the reception of code being handled?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know anything about codebase or the technology either. Although I do have access to the code. It would be a great help if you could tell me where I could find that part?

Comment: If you're in Visual Studio, hit CTRL+SHIFT+F, then search for "userworkinsert" and you will find the relevant part fast :)

Comment: Ok, that's better - looks like there is a TON of stuff that can go wrong there, since the parameters coming in aren't checked or verified at all before being pushed straight into the database. In terms of performance, using the database as your "validation" is very very slow. Having said that, I can't really see where the bug would be on the UserID question. You would have to debug it to see exactly where it crashes, possibly also checking the database for errors.